# uninitialized local variable in function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to modularize a program I had working before. I've taken everything out of main and put it into functions. My problem is that when I had everything in Main it worked fine without having to initialize the variables and wait for the user to input what the numbers were. Now that they are in functions I keep getting errors that they aren't initialized. Why is this? If I make them all 0 then when the user inputs their numbers the variables stay 0. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void displayMenu();
void findSquareArea();
void findCircleArea();
void findTriangleArea();

const double PI = 3.14159;

int main()
{  

displayMenu();

return 0;
}

void displayMenu() {

int choice;

do {
    cout << "Make a selection for the shape you want to find the area of: \n";
    cout << "1. Square\n";
    cout << "2. Circle\n";
    cout << "3. Right Triangle\n";
    cout << "4. Quit\n";

    cin >> choice;


    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        findSquareArea();
        break;

    case 2:
        findCircleArea();
        break;

    case 3:
        findTriangleArea();
        break;

    case 4:
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    default:
        cout << "Invalid entry, please run program again.";
        break;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        cout << "\n";
    }
} while (choice != 4);

}

void findSquareArea() {

double length,
    area = length * length;

cout << "Enter the length of the square.";
cin >> length;
cout << "The area of your square is " << area << endl;

}

void findCircleArea() {

double radius,
    area = PI * (radius * radius);

cout << "Enter the radius of the circle.\n";
cin >> radius;
cout << "The area of your circle is " << area << endl;

}

void findTriangleArea() {

double height, base,
    area = (.5) * (base) * (height);

cout << "Enter the height of the triangle.\n";
cin >> height;
cout << "Enter the length of the base.\n";
cin >> base;
cout << "The area of your triangle is " << area << endl;

}
```

Comment: `double length, area = length * length;` you utilize `length` before initializing it

Comment: so the issue is where I'm initializing area as length * length?

Comment: That is a general pattern of such problems, you do the same with `base` and `radius`

Comment: please create a [mcve]. Don't just dump all of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have expressions that are based on uninitialized variables, e.g. `area = length * length` in `double length, area = length * length`; Note that C++ is not like, for example, Excel, where you can define a formula which is automatically recalculated when parameters change. The "formula" is rather evaluated right where the code is stated.

So your code like ...

```
double length,
    area = length * length;

cout << "Enter the length of the square.";
cin >> length;
cout << "The area of your square is " << area << endl;
```

should be written like ...

```
double length = 0.0, area;


cout << "Enter the length of the square.";
cin >> length;
area = length * length;
cout << "The area of your square is " << area << endl;
```

Comment: That's what I did thanks to VTT comments, but I'll upvote this since it's the first right answer.